# How to change alignment of \uplevel in exam class?

Tags: environments, alignment, exam

I am trying to mimic the exam style of the Dutch central exams (high school) in LaTeX so my students can get used to the exam format. I am using the exam package from LaTeX and I have almost nearly copied the whole style. But I can not seem to figure out how to change the alignment of the `\uplevel{}`  command. The `\uplevel{}` gives me accesses to using packages like `amsmath`, `chemfig` and `mhchem` which are very handy for making chemistry tests.

The aim is to get the following style:

[image]

The style has the following demands:

1. The start of the line under the question title should be aligned with the points on the left.
2. The start of the title of the question should be aligned with the question number.
3. The information about the question and the question should be aligned.

What I have made so far:

[image]

This style does not match the demands of the exam above because:

1. The start of the line under the question title is aligned with the `\uplevel{}` alignment.
2. The start of the title of the question is aligned with the `\uplevel{}` alignment.
3. The information about the question is aligned with the `\uplevel{}` alignment.

This is what I have tried for points 1 and 2:

```
\definecolor{exam-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newcommand{\onderwerp}[1]{
\raggedright
{\textbf{\Large #1}} \linebreak {\color{exam-gray} \rule{\textwidth}{1.5 mm}}
}
```

But I can not seem to separate the alignment like the Dutch exam does. To generate a title of a question I put the title in the like this:

```
\uplevel{ \onderwerp{Lewisstructuren uit examens}}
```

For point 3 I have tried to put the information about the questions not in the `\uplevel{}` command but this yielded errors with the `chemfig` and `mhchem` packages. An example for how it looks now:

```
\uplevel{\textit{2016 - II} \\
Het zure karakter (...) van de geconjugeerde \ce{R-OSO_{3}^{-}} groep meerdere grensstructuren mogelijk zijn.}
```

I have searched endlessly online for people with a similar problem. But I have not found a problem like this or a solution to another problem that applicable. Maybe the solution is very easy, but I can not seem to find the answer.

I have used the following code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, addpoints]{exam}   
%\usepackage{fontspec}                          
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}                     
\usepackage{chemfig}                            
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}                  
\usepackage{xcolor}                             

%\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=Font/,
%BoldFont        = {Arial_Bold.ttf},
%ItalicFont      = {Arial_Italic.ttf},
%BoldItalicFont  = {Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf}
%]{Arial.ttf}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}                                                 % Zorgt voor kop- en voettekst
\firstpagefooter{\footnotesize{5VA3}}{\thepage\ / \numpages}{}    % Footer p1  {L}{M}{R}
\runningfooter{\footnotesize{5VA3}}{\thepage\ / \numpages}{}      % Footer >p1 {L}{M}{R}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}                                   % Regelafstand 1.15
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                                             % Niet inspringen na witregel

\pointsinmargin                                                         % Zet punten in marge       
\pointformat{\scriptsize{\thepoints}}                                   % Maakt punten klein
\pointname{\scriptsize{p \hspace{2mm}}}                                 % Zet p achter punten en voegt

\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thequestion \hspace{2mm}}                  % Ruimte tussen tekst en vraag
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\small\arabic{question}}           % Maakt vragen bold

\definecolor{exam-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newcommand{\onderwerp}[1]{
\raggedright
{\textbf{\Large #1}} \linebreak {\color{exam-gray} \rule{\textwidth}{1.5 mm}}
}

\begin{document}
\sloppy                         % Hierdoor lopen de woorden niet door in de rechter marge
\setlength{\parskip}{4mm}       % 4 mm afstand naar volgende paragraaf 
\begin{questions}

\uplevel{ \onderwerp{Lewisstructuren uit examens}}
\uplevel{\textit{2016 - II} \\
Het zure karakter van de sulfonzuurgroep wordt onder andere veroorzaakt doordat van de geconjugeerde \ce{R-OSO_{3}^{-}} groep meerdere grensstructuren mogelijk zijn.}

\question[4]
Geef de Lewisstructuur van de groep \ce{R-OSO_{3}^{-}} en leg uit dat van deze groep meerdere grensstructuren bestaan. Geef in de tekening formele lading(en) aan. \\
Neem aan dat de covalentie van zwavel 6 is. De overige atomen in de weergegeven Lewisstructuur moeten voldoen aan de oktetregel. Laat hierbij de groep R buiten beschouwing. \\
Hint: een grensstructuur is een structuur waarin de atomen dezelfde verbinding hebben, maar de elektronen op een andere plek in de structuur zitten. Zo heeft het carbonaat ion 3 grensstructuren (zie pagina 167). 

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Does somebody know how to solve this/ these problem(s)? It would be very helpful for me! :)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please a minimum compilable code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`  that reproduces your current output.

Comment: I've added the code I used so far in the description (without the Arial font). Thanks for replying.

Comment: Ik maak mijn toetsen ook in LateX in een layout die zoveel mogelijk op het CE lijkt. Ik heb ondertussen een mooie basis staan. Ik heb zeer zeker geen expert in LaTeX, maar als je ervaringen wilt delen dan sta ik daar zeker voor open! Ik geef wiskunde.

(Ik kon niet zo snel vinden of en zo ja waar ik je een privébericht kan sturen...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this layout fits your requirements. Your code was very close.

(marked with `<<<<<` the lines changed or added)

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, addpoints]{exam}   
%\usepackage{fontspec}                          
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}                     
\usepackage{chemfig}                            
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}                  
\usepackage{xcolor}                         

%\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=Font/,
%BoldFont        = {Arial_Bold.ttf},
%ItalicFont      = {Arial_Italic.ttf},
%BoldItalicFont  = {Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf}
%]{Arial.ttf}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}                                                 % Zorgt voor kop- en voettekst
\firstpagefooter{\footnotesize{5VA3}}{\thepage\ / \numpages}{}    % Footer p1  {L}{M}{R}
\runningfooter{\footnotesize{5VA3}}{\thepage\ / \numpages}{}      % Footer >p1 {L}{M}{R}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}                                   % Regelafstand 1.15
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                                             % Niet inspringen na witregel

\pointsinmargin                                                         % Zet punten in marge       
\pointformat{\scriptsize{\thepoints}}                                   % Maakt punten klein
\pointname{\scriptsize{p\hspace{2ex}}}                                 % Zet p achter punten en voegt <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thequestion\hspace{3mm}}                  % Ruimte tussen tekst en vraag <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\small\arabic{question}}           % Maakt vragen bold

\definecolor{exam-gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newcommand{\onderwerp}[1]{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \raggedright\sffamily
    {\textbf{\Large #1}}\linebreak {\hspace*{-4ex}\color{exam-gray} \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+8ex}{1.5 mm}}
}
    
\makeatletter
\long\def\uplevel#1{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \par\bigskip
    \vbox{%
        \leftskip=\@totalleftmargin%
        \advance\@totalleftmargin-\leftmargin%
        \advance\linewidth\leftmargin%
        #1%
    }%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \sloppy                         % Hierdoor lopen de woorden niet door in de rechter marge
    \setlength{\parskip}{4mm}       % 4 mm afstand naar volgende paragraaf 
    \begin{questions}       
        
        \uplevel{\onderwerp{Lewisstructuren uit examens}}
        \uplevel{\textit{2016 - II} \\
            Het zure karakter van de sulfonzuurgroep wordt onder andere veroorzaakt doordat van de geconjugeerde \ce{R-OSO_{3}^{-}} groep meerdere grensstructuren mogelijk zijn.}
        
        \question[4]
        Geef de Lewisstructuur van de groep \ce{R-OSO_{3}^{-}} en leg uit dat van deze groep meerdere grensstructuren bestaan. Geef in de tekening formele lading(en) aan. \\
        Neem aan dat de covalentie van zwavel 6 is. De overige atomen in de weergegeven Lewisstructuur moeten voldoen aan de oktetregel. Laat hierbij de groep R buiten beschouwing. \\
        Hint: een grensstructuur is een structuur waarin de atomen dezelfde verbinding hebben, maar de elektronen op een andere plek in de structuur zitten. Zo heeft het carbonaat ion 3 grensstructuren (zie pagina 167). 
        
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Used `exam.cls    2021/02/26 Version 2.7`

Comment: Very nice! It works very nicely. Thank you so much! :)